# Select tag .change -> if value == 3 -> remove attr 'disabled' of another select

Tags: jquery, select

I have 6 select tag.

> FIRST: select with value = 2, 3, 4, 5 
>   SECOND & THIRST: select
>   doesn't has attribute 'disabled'
>   FORTH, FIFTH, SIXTH: select has attribute
>   'disabled'

I need:

> if select value == 3  ->  FORTH remove attribute 'disabled'
>  if select
>   value == 4  ->  FORTH & FIFTH remove attribute 'disabled'
>  if select
>   value == 5  ->  FORTH & FIFTH & SIXTH remove attribute 'disabled'
>  and
>   else select value == 2  ->  FORTH, FIFTH, SIXTH: add attribute 'disabled'

This is my script

```
<select id="FIRST">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select id="SECOND">
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
</select>

<select id="THIRST">
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
</select>

<select id="FORTH" disabled>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
</select>

<select id="SIXTH" disabled>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
</select>

<select id="FIFTH" disabled>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
  <option value=" ">Something</option>
</select>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#FIRST').change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() == 3) {
        $('#FORTH').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else if $(this).val() == 4) {
        $('#FORTH, #FIFTH').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 5) {
        $('#FORTH, #FIFTH, #SIXTH').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#FORTH, #FIFTH, #SIXTH').attr('disabled');
    };
        });
});
 </script>
```

Is that correct? That does not run

Comment: Well, if it doesn't run it's not correct. Keep the JavaScript error console open to see the error messages.

Comment: you could try using Chrome or Firebug to debug your JavaScript and show where the errors are.  The Web Developer chrome extension is the best thing ever too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been said, you have 2 syntax errors, one on the first `else if` and one on the second to last line where you're missing a closing bracket `)`

Though it's not what you're asking, this is a perfect example of when to use a switch case to avoid ugly, inefficent code, see the example below:

```
$('#FIRST').change(function (event) {
    switch (+$(this).val())
    {
        case 3: $('#FORTH').prop('disabled', false); break;
        case 4: $('#FORTH, #FIFTH').prop('disabled', false); break;
        case 5: $('#FORTH, #FIFTH, #SIXTH').prop('disabled', false); break;
        default: $('#FORTH, #FIFTH, #SIXTH').prop('disabled', true); break;
    }
});
```

EDIT - You also had a confusing ordering problem with your markup where SIXTH and FIFTH where round the wrong way, I fixed this (and renamed THIRST to THIRD) and you can see a working demo of the above code working with the revised markup in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WNre/1/)

To achieve what is described in the comment from Derek Henderson, the code above can be updated to look like this:

```
$('#FIRST').change(function (event) {
    switch (+$(this).val())
    {
        case 3: $('#FORTH').prop('disabled', false); $('#FIFTH, #SIXTH').prop('disabled', true); break;
        case 4: $('#FORTH, #FIFTH').prop('disabled', false); $('#SIXTH').prop('disabled', true); break;
        case 5: $('#FORTH, #FIFTH, #SIXTH').prop('disabled', false); break;
        default: $('#FORTH, #FIFTH, #SIXTH').prop('disabled', true); break;
    }
});
```

And here's an example of that working on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WNre/2/).

Comment: +1 for using a switch.  However, I'm not sure this does what I *think* user2148971 wants. To do that, for each case specify both the disabled and enabled controls.  Otherwise, selecting 3 or 4 after selecting 5 will have no effect at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the code if OP wants to do that, it's worth noting that none of code from the OP or any answers would have achieved this and is not at all related to using a switch. +1 your comment as it's added useful information.

Comment: sorry for very late thanks, I'm new here so didn't know rules

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 syntax errors in your code, you are missing `})` for closing `change` handler and `(` for one of the `else if` statements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#FIRST').change(function(event) {
       if ($(this).val() == 3) {
           $('#FORTH').prop('disabled', false);
       }
       else if ($(this).val() == 4) { // here
           $('#FORTH, #FIFTH').prop('disabled', false);
       }
       else if ($(this).val() == 5) {
           $('#FORTH, #FIFTH, #SIXTH').prop('disabled', false);
       }
       else {
           $('#FORTH, #FIFTH, #SIXTH').prop('disabled', true);
       }
   }) // and here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a (.  Change:

```
 else if $(this).val() == 4) {
    $('#FORTH, #FIFTH').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

To

```
 else if ($(this).val() == 4) {
    $('#FORTH, #FIFTH').prop('disabled', false);
}
```